# Azure Function Logger does not write data

Tags: c#, azure, logging, azure-functions

I have the following code:

```
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        var services = builder.Services;

        services.AddLogging();
```

and

```
public class FunctionSendGridTest
{
    private readonly IMicrosoftGraphEmailService _graphApiEmailService;
    private readonly ILogger<FunctionSendGridTest> _logger;


    public FunctionSendGridTest(IMicrosoftGraphEmailService graphApiEmailService, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _graphApiEmailService = graphApiEmailService;
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<FunctionSendGridTest>();
    }
```

but when I try to write log:

```
    [FunctionName("FunctionSendGridTest")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log
        )
    {
        log.LogInformation("FunctionSendGridTest processed a request.");
        _logger.LogInformation("FunctionSendGridTest processed a request (logger).");
```

it writes only

> "FunctionSendGridTest processed a request."

but not

> "FunctionSendGridTest processed a request (logger)."

why so? I want to have behavior exactly as `log.LogInformation`

I tried also

```
    public FunctionSendGridTest(IMicrosoftGraphEmailService graphApiEmailService, ILogger<FunctionSendGridTest> logger)
    {
        _graphApiEmailService = graphApiEmailService;
        _logger = logger;
    }
```

instead of `ILoggerFactory loggerFactory` and have the same as with factory

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the workaround below

In **startup.cs**

```
public  override  void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Services.AddScoped<Customlog>();
}
```

In **Httptrigger** I am using the `custom logger`

```
public  class  httptrigger
{
    private  readonly Customlog customLog;
    public  httptrigger(Customlog customLog)
    {
        this.customLog = customLog ?? throw  new ArgumentNullException(nameof(customLog));
    }
    
    [FunctionName("httptrigger")]
    public  async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,ILogger log)
    {
        //Default log
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
        //Custom log
        customLog.testlog("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
        
        string name = req.Query["name"];
        string requestBody = await  new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
        name = name ?? data?.name;
        string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response." : $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";
        
        //Custom log
        customLog.testlog(responseMessage);
        return  new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
    }
}
```

Same I am using in the **timer trigger**

```
public class TriggerFunction
{
    private readonly Customlog customLog;
    public TriggerFunction(Customlog customLog)
    {
        this.customLog = customLog ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(customLog));
    }
    
    [FunctionName("TriggerFunction")]
    public void Run([TimerTrigger("0/10 * * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
    
    {
        //Default log
        log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
        //Custom log
        customLog.testlog("C# Timer trigger function executed at");
    }
}
```

In **customlog.cs** I am adding the below lines

```
public  class  Customlog
{
    public  Customlog(ILogger<Customlog> logger, TelemetryClient telemetry)
    {
        Logger = logger ?? throw  new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
        Telemetry = telemetry ?? throw  new ArgumentNullException(nameof(telemetry));
    }
    
    public  void testlog(string mylog)
    {
        Logger.LogInformation("TESTLOG:"+mylog);
        //Telemetry log
        Telemetry.TrackTrace("TESTLOG: " + mylog, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts.SeverityLevel.Information);
        Telemetry.TrackEvent("TESTLOG:" + mylog);
    }
    
    public ILogger<Customlog> Logger { get; }
    public TelemetryClient Telemetry { get; }
}
```

I could see both logs
[image]

Comment: does not work :( No writting to log

Comment: Did you try the flow which I mentioned?

Comment: Please go through the flow which I have followed. I can able to see both **ILogger** and **custom log**.

Comment: Yes, exactly as you wrote